# How to efficiently divide each value with the sum of the values in the same group?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame as follows:

```
F1  F2  F3
x   y   n1
x   z   n2
x   a   n3
x   b   n4
t   y   n5
t   y2  n6
t   y3  n7
t   y4  n8
```

For each row, I want to create another dataframe with another field `F4` as follows:

```
F1  F2  F3  F4
x   y   n1  n1/(n1+2+n3+n4)
x   z   n2  n2/(n1+2+n3+n4)
x   a   n3  n3/(n1+2+n3+n4)
x   b   n4  n4/(n1+2+n3+n4)
t   y   n5  n5/(n5+n6+n7+n8)
t   y2  n6  n6/(n5+n6+n7+n8)
t   y3  n7  n7/(n5+n6+n7+n8)
t   y4  n8  n8/(n5+n6+n7+n8)
```

That is, each `F3` should be divided by the sum of `F3`'s having the same `F1` value.

How to perform these aggregations in Spark Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window functions are convenient when adding additional columns that depend on a group/partition of the data. In this case you can use a window function to compute the sum of all `F3` values partitioned on the `F1` column.

It can be solved as follows:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("F1")
val df2 = df.withColumn("F4", $"F3" / sum($"F3").over(w))
```